# How to insert an Array in Node js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Well, I am stuck since a long time on how to treat properly an array in Node js in order to persist it in my mongobd database.
I tried a lot of stuff, i am feeling close to success, but still stuck with it with the var filmDataSchema and the var film syntax.

I really need a little help, please:

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't that work?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Did you take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please add some code examples of what you've tried already and specifics on where you get stuck, then we can help you

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `mongoose`? it's an elegant mongodb object modeling for node.js and has a really nice interface to handle arrays so let's say you have a student model with grades array and you want to add a new grade, you can use the '$push' (if) or `$addToSet` operators like so

```
StudentModel.update(
   { _id: student._id }, 
   { $addToSet: { grades: grade } }
);

StudentModel.update(
   { _id: student._id }, 
   { $push: { grades: grade } }
);
```

use `$addToSet` if you want only unique items to be pushed into array. use `$push` if you just want to add the object to array whether or not the object is already there

more about mongoose can be found here https://mongoosejs.com/